# How to remove JSON extra row in Java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to post a json to the server. but the json got something wrong. The JSON is including "id" and "record_id", But I didn't set the 2 value. How can I remove it from my json??

```
final Record rec = new Record();

rec.setAccountbook(bookCid);
rec.setUser(pref.getString(Constants.USER_ID, ""));
rec.setCreatedAt(currentDateandTime);
rec.setRecordType(Integer.toString(valtype));
rec.setRemark(strremark);
rec.setAmount(Double.toString(dbamount));
rec.setAsset(strasset);
rec.setCategory(type);

//I didn't set this 2, but this 2 show in the json
//rec.setId(1);
//rec.setRecord_id(1); 

String json = new Gson().toJson(rec);
Log.d("JSON_MSG",""+json);
```

Result

```
D/JSON_MSG:
{  
    "accountbook":"04e19a16-ea72-43da-b2b8-fe388ec56fd4",
    "amount":"522.0",
    "asset":"Cash",
    "category":"吃喝",
    "createdAt":"2018-12-19",
    "id":0,
    "recordType":"1",
    "record_id":0,
    "remark":"",
    "user":"43"
}
```

Java: Record Class

```
private int id;
private int record_id;
private String cid, amount, accountbook, asset, createdAt, recordType, remark, category, user;
private String record_cid, record_amount, record_category, record_book, record_type, record_remark, record_createdAt, record_asset, record_user;

//Declare Constructor
public Record(String amount, String accountbook, String asset, String createdAt, String recordType, String remark, String category, String user) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.accountbook = accountbook;
    this.asset = asset;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.recordType = recordType;
    this.remark = remark;
    this.category = category;
    this.user = user;
}

//All the setter & getter
```

Comment: Do you have toString method too??

Comment: Ya, but not include the id & record_id.

Comment: Do you want these two fields whenever they have proper values or you completely want to ignore these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transient keyword on your id field.The modifier transient in java can be applied to field members of a class to turn off serialization on these field members. Every field marked as transient will not be serialized.

Look into transient in [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/transient-keyword-in-java-with-real-time-example/) link

For Instance,

```
private transient int id;
private int record_id;
private String cid, amount, accountbook, asset, createdAt, recordType, remark, category, user;
private String record_cid, record_amount, record_category, record_book, record_type, record_remark, record_createdAt, record_asset, record_user;

//Declare Constructor
public Record(String amount, String accountbook, String asset, String createdAt, String recordType, String remark, String category, String user) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.accountbook = accountbook;
    this.asset = asset;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.recordType = recordType;
    this.remark = remark;
    this.category = category;
    this.user = user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add @JsonIgnore annotation on the field 

`@JsonIgnore
private int id;`